# How to change a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making my own image gallery and have a decent version working.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydysh4pt/)

I'm trying to change the link for the main image when a thumbnail image is clicked but not sure how to do this or if it can be done. I can assign a link to the thumbnail but then you can't use the gallery so I need to find a way to change the link for the main image.

currently using the following to change the image and hoping I can get help changing the link within the same function

```
$('#thumb1').click(function() {
   $('#imgDisplay').anystretch("images/url.jpg", {speed: 1000});
   $fancy magik needs to happen here I'm guessing; 
});
```

tried adding

```
$("a[href='google link']").attr('href', 'other link');
```

to my function but it broke it, still working on it

Comment: What do you mean by 'the link for the main image'? The current fiddle doesn't seem to have a hyperlink to change...

Comment: currently working on it, just updated and now I lost the functionality when I added $("a[href='http://google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://live.com/');

Comment: Is it the `src` of the big image your trying to change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2aw459h9/ works for me - only added it on the first thumb.

Comment: it's the href link, eventually all the thumbnails will be linked to other things but there's only one big image and the thumbnails are used to change that main image, that's what anystretch does, but I need the link for that to change when I change it's image

Comment: thank you S McCrohan, that seems to do the trick. Amazing how a few little changes makes things work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to give a link to main image.

[myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydysh4pt/5/)

But to clarify you, you will not only need to give a link to an element to redirect to a page. you can also do some js tricks to do that using `window.location.href` like...

```
$('#imgDisplay').click(function() {
   window.location.href = 'your path here';
});
```

And OWWWWWW... to make your code more readable and clean.. for element with the same functionality, use class instead of an id for your event listeners.